# how to modify the data-width attribute in a facebook like box on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook, responsive-design

I'm inserting a facebook like box into a WP homepage within a responsive theme, and need to resize the width according to the viewport used.

The HTML code to place the like box is the following:

```
<div class="fb-like-box" id="epo" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/fbuser" data-width="880" data-height="400" data-colorscheme="light" data-show-faces="true" data-header="false" data-stream="true" data-show-border="true"></div>
```

I already have a jQuery function to detect window width but can't find any way to replace the "data-width" attribute in the div.

```
$(window).ready(function() {
var wi = $(window).width();  
var div = document.getElementById("epo");


$(window).resize(function() {
    var wi = $(window).width();

    if (wi <= 480){
        div.data-width('300');
        }
    else if (wi <= 767){
        div.data-width('460');
        }
    else if (wi <= 980){
        div.data-width('760');
        }
    else if (wi <= 1200){
        div.data-width('880');
        }
    else {
        div.data-width('880');
        }
});            
});
```

Comment: Just setting `data-width` to a new value will not work, because the element gets only parsed once. You will have to modify the width of the inserted `iframe` element directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As CBroe stressed above, the width of the data is already loaded. But changing the iframe width did not work either. So I worked on this solution.

I inserted on the page four ID divs, inside them I placed the code for the FB likebox changing the data-width attribute to fit the four different responsive widths the theme has, fine-tuning the widths and paddings with firebug:

```
<div id="fb-full">
    <div class="fb-like-box" id="epo1" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/fbuser" data-width="880" data-height="400" data-colorscheme="light" data-show-faces="true" data-header="false" data-stream="true" data-show-border="true">
    </div>
</div>

<div id="ipad">
<div class="fb-like-box" id="epo2" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/fbuser" data-width="706" data-height="400" data-colorscheme="light" data-show-faces="true" data-header="false" data-stream="true" data-show-border="true">
    </div>
</div>

<div id="mobile-h">
<div class="fb-like-box" id="epo3" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/fbuser" data-width="416" data-height="400" data-colorscheme="light" data-show-faces="true" data-header="false" data-stream="true" data-show-border="true">
    </div>
</div>

<div id="mobile-v">
<div class="fb-like-box" id="epo4" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/fbuser" data-width="260" data-height="400" data-colorscheme="light" data-show-faces="true" data-header="false" data-stream="true" data-show-border="true">
    </div>
</div>
```

Then I added this code the style.css

```
#ipad, #mobile-h, #mobile-v { display:none; }
```

And in responsive.css, I added the different combinations of ***display:none !important; and display:block !important;*** to show or hide divs depending on the current display width.

Answer (score 0):

I used the parent div to calculate the size and made it fully responsive.

`

```
<div id="fb-parent">
    <script>(function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.6";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
        <div id="fb-page" class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/fbUser" data-tabs="timeline" data-width="500" data-height="250" data-small-header="true" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="true" data-show-facepile="false"></div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<script>
    $(function () {
        var fb_width = $('#fb-parent').width();
        fb_width.toFixed();
        var fb_height = $('#fb-parent').height();
        fb_height.toFixed();
        $('#fb-page').attr("data-width", fb_width);
        $('#fb-page').attr("data-height", fb_height);
    });
</script>`
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to use this:

```
$("#epo").attr("data-width", "300px")
```

Answer (score -1):

Your `data-width` is an attribute. To set a attribute's value try

```
div.attr('data-width', '300px')
```